# To what extent are "What does [thing] do" questions OK to ask?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

For example the highly popular question of [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/13629335) seems to be on-topic for Stack Overflow. I'm curious about something similar and wouldn't even know where to begin to research a lower level topic.

To make my practical example, but not to discuss that particular example, I'll explain what I want to ask.

I noticed that in the C implementation of the [tk-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tk-toolkit) in Python there is a undocumented method [GetVar](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_tkinter.c#L1770). Just through initializing the `_tkinter.create` I can use `self.getvar` even though the class does not inherit those methods.

But this sounds like a question of *Why does it work* and those seem to be off-topic, since they do not really ask about a specific programming problem, but same would apply to the seemingly on-topic question of *What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?*.

So I wonder how the community feels about this and where is the line to for a *[good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)*?

Comment: *Why does such-and-such from class whatever seem to exist when the class doesn't inherit those methods* sounds like a specific programming question to me.

Comment: Note: in general it is not really a good idea to look at really old questions to make comparisons. Things have changed quite a lot since 2008, what flew back then does not necessarily fly today. Try to look at how recent questions do for more realistic comparisons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both your examples are on topic. [As President James K. Polk notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424444/to-what-extend-are-what-does-it-do-question-ok-to-ask#comment955931_424444), clarifying how a specific functionality works is by itself a "specific programming problem" -- that phrase does not limit the scope of this site to debugging or snippet writing questions. Furthermore, the answer will be relevant when it comes to deciding whether and how to use said functionality.

Comment: Agree, even though my practical example resulted been self-answered with a *silly mistake*. I asked myself often in the past **if** I should answer *such* questions. There are those phrases like *StackOverflow is not a group of personal trainers* and *Please ask about a specific programming issue*. It's nice to have clarified the fact that *explaining a specific functionality* is welcomed here.